# Why won't my query let me assign primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

Just a note, I'm pretty new to SQL.

I'm using MySQL and using the app SequelPro.

I receive this error when I try to make a table:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 4"

This is the code I'm using to make my table:

```
CREATE TABLE klout_scores_3 (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    score INT(11)
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You'll avoid some frustration if you keep this in mind: MySQL syntax errors that mention *"the right syntax to use near '...'"* **always** mean that the thing inside the quotes represents the *beginning* of something unexpected, which is why the message says **"near"** -- not "at."  The error is often *near but before* the text shown.  Here, the parser thought you were saying `score INT(11) PRIMARY KEY`, which is an alternate way of specifying a primary key column, and in that light, `(id) )` blew its mind, but the query seemed valid (though it was misinterpreted) up until that point.

Comment: Similarly, `...the right syntax to use near ''` means the parser made it all the way the end of the query, and considers that to be impossible.  A query that throws exactly this error is `SELECT * FROM;`.  Clearly, when the end is reached, the server realizes that there's something mandatory (like a table name) that's missing.

Comment: that really gives me a deeper sense of the error message. before, I was largely ignoring them. thank you michael.

Answer (score 3):

```
score INT(11)
```

You want a comma `,` at end of that line.

Comment: Woah, yea, so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what this means? ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @Sebastian: MySQL has many "engines" for storing data. InnoDB is one type. It allows to auto-validate data so it can help eliminate problem garbage IN.
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 tells the engine that when a string is saved, it's "encoded" in utf8, which is a way for international accented characters to be stored but leaves the Western characters intact.

Comment: It's really amazing that people take the time to help out new learners (like me). I hope to pay it forward in the future like you're doing now. Thanks Jacques.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is being interpreted like this:

```
CREATE TABLE klout_scores_3 (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    score INT(11) PRIMARY KEY
    (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `(id)` part is really confusing to MySQL and it's raising an error right there. Although adding a `,` after the `INT(11)` part will fix it, a better solution is to move the declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE klout_scores_3 (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    score INT(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It's a little concerning that you have a table name like `klout_scores_3`, as that suggests you have N of these tables. Relational database design and [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
rules *strongly* frowns on this, you should have a singular table with some kind of `..._id` column to relate the scores to whatever record that `3` identifies.